# Conditionally extracting rows of CSV files?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Germany,1928,Food
Iceland,1943,Oil
France,1923,Plastics
Russia,1901,Steal
South Africa,1932,Silver
Russia,1905,Gold
Brazil,1901,Platinum
```

I want it to search through the first column and pull a row if it hits the word "Russia."

This is what my code looks like currently:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('country.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    datalist = []
    for row in data:
        if len (row) != 0:
            datalist = datalist + [row]
csvfile.close()

column_names = datalist[0]  # LIST OF COLUMNS
```

How would I go about pulling the whole row?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. What do you mean by "pull the whole row"? You are adding the whole row to your list. Please explain what you really want to do. Also, your code does never compare any field to `Russia`, as stated in your description.

Comment: Off topic: IF you use `with open...` to open a file, the closing of it will be done automatically after the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html):

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'Russia', datalist)
[['Russia', '1901', 'Steal'], ['Russia', '1905', 'Gold']]
```